# Executing a shell script from remote server on local machine

Tags: shell, ssh, shell-script, remote

Imagine a shell script on the remote server as

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /test.x
```

How can I (if possible) to execute this script from my local machine to delete `/test.x` file on my local machine. Obviously, the solution should be with something like `ssh` authorization, but without downloading the script file from the remote server.

In fact, I want to use the remote script as a provider of shell commands to be run on the local machine.

Comment: put it on a filesystem shared via NFS.  Mount the NFS filesystem on the local machine, and run `/path/to/nfs/mount/script.sh` from the local machine.  The local machine's `/test.x` file will be removed.

Comment: `but without downloading the script file from the remote server`: How do you expect the remote script to work on your local machine without sending the script content to the local machine ?!?

Comment: @BatchyX I mean reading the `commands` somehow, instead of downloading the entire script and executing it locally.

Comment: @All: bash stores command definitions by more-or-less saving their definition (use `set` to see that). You won't gain anything by trying to send the bare minimum to make the command work. Just think about the dependency hell if command `do_that` depends on `do_this` to work properly. You could still do it proxy-style (e.g. `do_that () { download_do_that_definition_from_server && do_that; }`), but it's still much more complicated than downloading the entire script and feeding it directly into the interpreter.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In many cases the idea you come up with isn't possible, or there are much better ways of getting to your objective.

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to download the content of the script in some way. You could do

```
ssh remote-host cat script.bash | bash
```

But that would have the same kind of problem as:

```
cat script.bash | bash
```

namely that stdin within the script would be the script itself (which could be an issue if commands within the script need to get some input from the user).

Then, a better alternative (but you'd need a shell with support for process substitution like ksh, zsh or bash) would be:

```
bash <(ssh remote-host cat script.bash)
```

Both approaches do download the script in that they retrieve its content, but they don't store it locally. Instead the content is fed to a pipe whose other end is read and interpreted by `bash`.

You can also have the content of the remote script executed in the current bash process with:

```
eval "$(ssh remote-host cat script.bash)"
```

But that downloads the script fully (and stores it in memory) before running it.

The obvious solution would be to do:

```
. <(ssh remote-host cat script.bash)
```

But beware that some versions of bash have issues with that.

Comment: Definitely, we need to somehow fetch the script content (commands), and using `bash` is quite, as it' my default. Seems a subtle and practical solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the remote filesystem containing the script with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). This makes the script a local file which you know how to execute.

```
mkdir /path/to/remote-host
sshfs remote-host:/ /path/to/remote-host
/path/to/remote-host/path/to/script
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but appeared as one of the first hits on google so here is an update years later.

This can be done on a single line using scp:

```
scp remote-host@/full-path/script.sh . && ./script.sh
```

The file is copied from the remote host to the current working directory then executed from the current working directory

Comment: The question was "without downloading the script file from the remote server".